# Is it a good practice to call a function inside a destructor in C++

Tags: c++

Is it a good practice to call a function inside a destructor which does some memory allocations internally. Because this is giving me access violations and other issues, For suppose

```
~Example(){
    Stop();
}
```

Here in this function Stop() does various things and also calls various other functions? Is it a good practice. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong in calling functions inside destructor the only important point to consider is that there should be no uncaught exceptions emitting from a destructor.

So, As long as you catch all the exceptions thrown from functions called within the destructor inside the desructor, You are safe.

Comment: Thanks Alok. I actually have one more question. Access Violations are encountered a lot in my application because of accessing or trying to clear a memory location in an heap that is not accessible. Can you tell me the basic thing to look at to solve this issue.

Comment: Don't use the `new` keyword. Don't use arrays.

Comment: @user1767288: The best advice: #1. To use dynamic memory as less as possible, the best C++ programs are ones with as little use of `new` as possible. Since #1 is practically impossible, #2 Use smart pointers instead of raw pointers. In either case if you still get memory access violations #3 Use a memory analyzer tool like valgrind to check the problems due to memory related bugs in your program. BTW, if you follow #1 and #2 properly, it is less likely that you will need #3.

Comment: Thanks Alok and Oswald

Comment: @user1767288: you shall ask suck things as separate question instead of inciting discussion

Comment: @Balog Pal Thanks Balog Pal. I will do it from the next time. I am new to this group so I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method from destructor is OK as long as it parts of the release/free up process. It's not advisable to perfrom an operation in reverse direction (acquiring resources/memory).

Answer (score 0):

Destructors are called (among others) when a `std::bad_alloc` is thrown, i.e. when a memory allocation failed. In that case, allocating memory in a destructor (or a function that is called by the destructor) will probably also fail, throwing an exception.

Throwing exceptions from a destructor is a really bad idea. Now, the destructor can catch that second `std::bad_alloc`, but I doubt that it has the necessary means to deal with it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it is ok, but can be dangerous. Keep in mind that some parts of the class may have already been destructed, so you might not be able to use everything in your class. In addition, try handling exceptions with-in the method.

Answer (score 0):

What the  destructor must do directly follows from the class state and design. So the choices are slim. You may do it inlined or calling a function. I see no reason why not call a function, especially if other member functions might use it too. (I.e see implementation of smart pointers having `reset()` function...)

You kinda imply that if the job is complex, we better not do it. Hmmm. Or the idea is  just not doing it in dtor, but leave that obligation to the programmer? As in going back to C? Ingoring that the most attractive feature of C++ is having dtors that enable RAII?

The one special thing to take care in a dtor is to swallow exceptions. With some luck they naturally can't happen. If there is a chance, it's indeed a good idea to have some public function to carry out most of the tasks, from where throwing is fair game.  (I.e `CFile` class closes the file in dtor, if it's still open. When used for output file, you're supposed to close it manually and deal with possible errors like unable to flush the last buffers on a full disk. You do all that and dtor will be relieved from hard work.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong about calling function within destructor by considering following synarios

**a) Unless function is virtual**

http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

**b) Avoid calling a member function that accesses data members that have already been destroyed**

```
bob::~bob()
  {
   delete ptr;
   this->increment(p); // undefined behavior
  }
```

**c) Prevent destructor throwing execption.**

If destructor is called because of exception is already application will terminate.